# How to add author name to a custom git alias?

Tags: git, git-alias

I have configured custom git alias that I use very frequently to see the complete graph and commit summary.

```
[alias]
    graph = log --oneline --all --decorate --graph
```

One thing I would like to add to this alias is the author name. I am trying to add it using the following format option configuration

```
git log --oneline --all --decorate --graph --format=format:"%h%x09%d%x09%an%x09%s"
```

This command seems to work but I do not get the nice color coding for commit hash and branch names. Can anyone please guide me as to how can I retain the color highlight for branch names and commit hashes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add the color code `%C(auto)` in front of your format string :

```
git log --all --decorate --graph --format=format:"%C(auto)%h%x09%d%x09%an%x09%s"
```

However, the author name is not colored *by default*, so you'll need a specific color code in front of it, like

```
git log --all --decorate --graph --format=format:"%C(auto)%h%x09%d%x09%C(blue)%an%C(reset)%x09%s"
```

Comment: Using `--format` supercedes `--oneline` so better just delete that option.

Comment: Perfect!! Thank you so much!